# Apache in WSL2 dos not work like localhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Dear colleagues in the network,

I'm trying to make my apache + php work localhost in the browser (chrome, firefox, edge ...) windows accessing localhost with apache installed on WSL2 with Ubuntu. But it does not work. Changing WSL to version 1 then works. After trying to understand a lot, I saw that WSL2 has a different IP than windows. Another band and another network submask so that WSL2 is not on localhost as WSL1 is.

Has anyone had this problem and managed to solve?

I'm new to Stack and can't post images yet. But I posted a print on the link: https://prnt.sc/t4abiu. If you can help me I appreciate it very much. Meanwhile I follow with Apache and PHP directly on windows.

PS .: Node, MariaDb, Postgres and MongoDb work as localhost normally. Apache only doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer. On Windows, port 80 is used by the www service. In my case, I just to uninstall the Windows feature and apache respond normally on port 80.
I hope this helps someone